# Firebase Crashlytics Webhook for Slack won't report recurring crashes

Tags: firebase, webhooks, slack, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have successfully set up the Webhook for Slack so that it will report crashes on Firebase Crashlytics. This is working completely fine!

However, when it detects the same crash multiple times,
it will report the first crash to the slack channel just fine, but the second time and after the same crash is detected, it does not report to the slack channel.

Is this how it's supposed to be?

I want to notify Slack of all crashes.

I can see in the slack integration settings section that the following settings that can be/is turned on.

Please check my image. ↓

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W343e.png)

Thank you for watching. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. As you can see in the screenshot `Triggered when your app experiences a crash Crashlytics hasn't seen before`, the notifications will be triggered when a new issue is detected.

After that, crashes that fall in the same issue won't trigger a notification as Crashlytics has already seen them before.

Check this [blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/09/how-to-set-up-crashlytics-alerting) post that explains this in detail for the different types of alerts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! All clear now :) Have a nice day!